# Turn off all code analyzer warnings in the IDE

Tags: matlab, editor, code-analysis

Is it possible to turn off all code analyzer warnings highlighting in the Matlab IDE, while keeping the code analyzer errors highlighting?
Looked around in preferences but didn't find any options except removing the underlining of warnings.
(They are still highlighted in code and visible at the right edge of the editor).

Workarounds I've found:

1. Disable all the warnings one by one, which is ridiculous because there is a list with hundreds of check boxes and no "un-check all".
2. Set the color of the warning highlighting to the background color of the editor.

Comment: `warning off` ?

Comment: I recommend you instead fix your code to not produce warnings. Those warnings really are meaningful, and help you improve your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the search bar in the Code Analyzer tab in the Preference menu to filter only warnings. Then you can select them all with `ctrl+A` and right click and select 'Disable'.

Then you can save your new settings as a new `mlint` config file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice one! I wrongly assumed that stuff like [ctrl, A] wouldn't work in such a list

Comment: @Anton I have to admit it was a bit of a surprise for me as well!